# Why create join table to make many to many relationship in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

All I follow the tutorial to make a simple many to many example,
http://hadiyahdotme.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/many-ways-to-do-many-to-many-hacker-notes/

I thought we only have to create another table "categorization "  to make many-to-many relations between category  and product model is enough!
why should we do `'rails generate migration create_categories_products_join'`

I can not understand, any idea can help me , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between category and product must be association (connection) so You must create special table for that.

**If You want use has_and_belongs_to_many:**

in models/product.rb:

```
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :join_table => :categories_products
...
```

in models/category.rb:

```
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :products, :join_table => :categories_products
...
```

in your migration file create_categories_products_join.rb

```
...
create_table :categories_products, :id => false do |t|
  t.references :product
  t.references :category
end
add_index :categories_products, [:product_id, :category_id]
add_index :categories_products, [:category_id, :product_id]
...
```

and remove categorization model `rails d model categorization`

**If You want use has_many :through**

in models/product.rb:

```
...
has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations 
...
```

in models/category.rb:

```
...
has_many :categorizations
has_many :products, :through => :categorizations 
...
```

in models/categorization.rb

```
...
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :category
...
```

in migration file create_categorizations

```
...
create_table :categorizations do |t|
  t.references :product
  t.references :category
  #...
  t.timestamps
end
add_index :categorizations, :category_id
add_index :categorizations, :product_id
...
```

migration create_categories_products_join You can remove `rails d migration create_categories_products_join`

Answer (score 0):

Its just two examples. First one is about `has_and_belongs_to_many` second one is about `has_many :through`.

If you are going with `has_many :through` and `categorization` table there is no need to create another table `categories_products`.

Choose one of the methods and you are done. I would recommend `has_many :through`. Its more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

When you have **has and belongs to many** (HABTM) relation you have to define a way to connect products to categories and vise versa. Thus, you should use join table.

In rails, when you code:

```
has_many :products, through: :categorizations
```

You should create a join table **categorizations** with reference to each one:

```
create_table "categorizations" do |t|
  t.integer  "category_id"
  t.integer  "product_id"
end
```

Then, you can access categories on specific product `product.categories` and products from category `category.products`

I suggest you to watch this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes-revised) and review this [code](https://github.com/railscasts/017-habtm-checkboxes-revised/tree/master/store-after)

Answer (score 0):

Now creating join table in Rails 4 is cool see available methods -

Migration method to create_join_table creates a HABTM join table. A typical use would be:

```
create_join_table :products, :categories
```

You can pass the option :table_name when you want to customize the table name. For example:

```
create_join_table :products, :categories, table_name: :categorization
```

will create a categorization table.

create_join_table also accepts a block, which you can use to add indices (which are not created by default) or additional columns:

```
create_join_table :products, :categories do |t|
  t.index :product_id
  t.index :category_id
end
```

[click here for more details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)